# How to implement async/await in event handler?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, eventemitter

I have problem implementing await inside event handler. For some reason, event handler doesn't wait for first process to finish before starting new one. Why is this weird behaviour so?

```js
const { EventEmitter } = require("events");

let alreadyRunning = false;

const sampleEventHandler = new EventEmitter();
sampleEventHandler.on("data", async (message) => {
  await heavyProcess(message);
});

async function heavyProcess(message) {
  console.log("New message: ", message);
  console.log("already running?: ", alreadyRunning);
  if (alreadyRunning) {
    console.log("Why doesn't it await for first task to complete fully before entering here?");
  }

  const rand = Math.random() * 1000;
  // set var here
  alreadyRunning = true;
  await sleep(rand);
  // unset here
  alreadyRunning = false;
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Emit event 5 times
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  sampleEventHandler.emit("data", i);
}
```

Comment: Dan.d has the answer in the comment below. Event emitters do not respect the return of the handlers (by design) so the Promise returned by your async handler is ignored (even if you tried await emit). I find this type of event handler becomes "reentrant" and you'll have loads of them seeming to run in parallel depending on what you're awaiting. Worse, the new events hog the single thread and can stall the async functions from resolving.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
The reason why it is not discarded is because you are doing `console.log` only. Add a return under it.

```
async function heavyProcess(message) {
  console.log("New message: ", message);
  console.log("already running?: ", alreadyRunning);
  if (alreadyRunning) {
    console.log("Why doesn't it await for first task to complete fully before entering here?");
     return // Actually stop executing
  }

  const rand = Math.random() * 1000;
  // set var here
  alreadyRunning = true;
  await sleep(rand);
  // unset here
  alreadyRunning = false;
}
```

Edit 2:
Following the comments: the required behaviour of OP is that the heavyProcess should only be happening once and only start a new one if the process has finished.

Every event is now starting a new heavyProcess as await just waits for a result, it is not blocking.

You'll have to introduce the blocking yourself in the event (or use RXJS exhaustMap or something similar).

```
let isProcessing = false;

sampleEventHandler.on("data", (message) => {
  if (isProcessing) { return; }
  isProcessing = true;
  const resetProcessing = () => isProcessing = false
  heavyProcess(message).then(resetProcessing, resetProcessing); // Reset of both complete and error
```

Comment: Are you implying that the tasks are executed in parallel inside event handler?

Comment: Yes, every event will execute the function, which triggers the heavyProcess. This should be reflected in your logging also. (the New message log will pop up 5x in a row)

Comment: My Qn is why if a new task is triggered when one is already in process? Why doesn't it wait? The code I have written is just a sample to reproduce a behaviour I am facing elsewhere.

Comment: That's the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. The `await` keyword indicates that you halt the execution of the function until you get a response from the function you are waiting on. In your example, this is happening for every event. You wait for a new heavyProcess to finish.

Comment: It can't wait. The emit loop doesn't await. It calls each listener synchronously and then discards the result. If you want a emit loop that awaits like it has a built in Promise.all, take the source of the eventemitter module and write one that does.

Comment: I'll update my answer if you wish to limit the execution in the event handler to only one

Answer (score 1):

You need to promisify `heavyProcess` function in order to using await with it successfuly:

```
function heavyProcess(message) {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("New message: ", message);
        console.log("already running?: ", alreadyRunning);
        if (alreadyRunning) {
            console.log("Why doesn't it await for first task to complete fully before entering here?");
        }

        const rand = Math.random() * 1000;
        // set var here
        alreadyRunning = true;
        await sleep(rand);
        // unset here
        alreadyRunning = false;
        resolve('Done');
    });
}
```